# Parse content within AngularJS directive before rendering template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an element on the page that has been rendered by the server. Let's call it a **playlist**. It's going to be a directive.
`<div playlist></div>`

A **playlist** contains a number of **tracks** before Angular compile time.
`<div class="Track" data-track-name="Pompeii" data-*="etc">...</div>`

Once the page is loaded I'm including AngularJS and parsing **playlist** and a directive.

When I initialise the **playlist** directive, I'd like to loop through it's contents before compiling it's template and using the data collected to draw **track** directives in an `ng-repeat` directive belonging to the **playlist** directive.

Questions:

1. Is there native functionality for parsing content before the template replaces any content within the directive tag? Once I'm in the directive controller the content has already been replaced.
2. Is there a better solution to my problem? I unfortunately have to use content already rendered on the page as a data-source as a solution to a whole bunch of requirements for this project
3. Could I use a track directive within my content from the server to avoid DOM manipulation?

Extra explanation

Before compile:

```
<div playlist>
   <div class="Track" data-track-name="Pompeii">Pompeii</div>
   <div class="Track" data-track-name="Weight of living">Weight of living</div>
</div>
```

After compile:

```
<div playlist>
   <!-- from playlist template -->
   <div class="Playlist">
       <div class="Playlist-controls">....</div>
       <div class="Playlist-tracks">
           <div track ng-repeat="track in tracks">
               <!-- from track template -->
               <div class="Track">...</div>
            </div>
       </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might be looking at this the wrong way. All data manipulation should be done in the controller and the directive should react to the changes. Is there any chance you could throw together a jsFiddle? The power of Angular is that you don't need to parse the DOM. Otherwise, there is the Link with pre-link and post-link to manipulate the DOM and the scope.

Comment: Actually, could you post your data structure/model for playlist? That might help me a bit in understanding what you want.

Comment: A playlist has a few controls, such as **playAll** or **queueAll**, whereas a track has things like **play** or **queue**. Other than that there's not much else to them as data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that I'm super happy with using [ngTransclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).

I write my content from the server for the **tracks** in their directive form:

```
<div track track-id="245" track-name="Pompeii" track-duration="3.24">Pompeii</div>
```

And in my **playlist** template, I use a `<div ng-transclude></div>` directive that takes the content of the **playlist** from the original DOM, parses it as individual directives and is injected into the specified part of the **playlist** template.

Comment: What's the point of the `playlist` then, if you can just render it on the server as well?

Comment: I agree with Beyers. The problem with the DOM parsing is that if the DOM changes, then Angular doesn't know about it since the model is not being updated. In a sense, your view has become the model. It may just be best to have the server just render it and do this without Angular at all.

Comment: A playlist in the non-js version is just a list of track names, but on the js version, it's an interactive device with a whole bunch of extra markup - same with each track.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming this is your data structure, you could easily do this all without a directive:

Data Structure/Controller

```
function ctrl($scope) {
$scope.Playlists = [
  { name: 'Playlist 1', tracks: [ 'Track 1', 'Track 2', ..., 'Track n'] },
  { name: 'Playlist 2', tracks: [ 'Track 1', 'Track 2', ..., 'Track n'] },
  ...
  { name: 'Playlist n', tracks: [ 'Track 1', 'Track 2', ..., 'Track n'] }
];
}
```

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="playlist in Playlists">
    <div> {{ playlist.name }} </div>
    <div ng-repeat="track in playlist.tracks">
       {{ track }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[edits]

Since you need to parse the DOM, you can use this directive to do it. It will parse the DOM and place it into a controller scope array. You can then pass this scope into a template or template URL. Use any jQuery you need to wipe the original DOM. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veJvY/1)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('playlist', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: {
            pre: function(scope, element) {
                $('.Track').each(function(index, ele) {
                   scope.tracks.push($(ele).attr('data-track-name')); 
                });
                console.log(scope.tracks);
            },
            post: function(scope, element) {
              // do any compiling, etc...    
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.tracks = [];
        }
    }
});
```

[edit #2] Including Beyer's suggestions. Adding this in case someone finds this useful in the future. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veJvY/2/)

Template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
        <div>My playlist controls</div>
        <div ng-repeat="track in tracks">
           {{ track }}
        </div>
   </script>
    <div playlist>
       <div class="Track" data-track-name="Pompeii">Pompeii</div>
       <div class="Track" data-track-name="Weight of living">Weight of living</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('playlist', function($compile, $templateCache) {
    var extractData = function(scope) {
        $('.Track').each(function(index, ele) {
            scope.tracks.push($(ele).attr('data-track-name'));
        });
    }

    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(ele, attr, ctrl) {
            return {
              pre: function preLink(scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
                  extractData(scope);
              },
              post: function postLink(scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
                  ele.html($templateCache.get("tpl.html"));
                  $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
              }
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            $scope.tracks = [];
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yup that's the ideal solution - but I absolutely have to use the content from the DOM on page load.

Comment: The trick with Angular is to think about the data first. Typically, with frameworks like jQuery, you think about the structure & layout. When I was starting out with Angular, I fell into the same trap. It may be that Angular is the wrong tool for your job. You might be better off with jQuery if you need to parse the DOM.

Comment: If jQuery is the best way to parse the data from the DOM that's all good - regardless I still need to use Angular for the rest of the application. Really I just want to find out if I can access the content of a directive before I bootstrap it. If not I'll have to rethink how I generate my data models using the DOM (which i'm not happy about - it's a requirement of this project though).

Comment: Hmm... I may have a solution for you.. gimmie a second to try it out on jsFiddle.

Comment: Forgot to mention, for me at least, I try to keep all my jQuery code within the pre and post link sections and try not to have any of it anywhere else, but I'm not sure if that's a best practice or not. It just keeps it tidy for me and my team to know where angular code is and jQuery code is.

Comment: oh I forgot, I think you could just set `replace: true, templateUrl: your template` and it'll replace the playlist inner DOM. That way, you can leverage all the angular functionality.

Comment: Just not that you shouldn't do DOM manipulation in pre-linking function: `Pre-linking function

Executed before the child elements are linked. Not safe to do DOM transformation since the compiler linking function will fail to locate the correct elements for linking.`

Comment: Also, I would do the extracting of data and manipulation in the compile function instead.

Comment: @Beyers Just out of curiosity, is there a reason to do extraction in the compile vs. pre? I've generally used pre just as a way of separating the logic from the post, but if it's better to do it in the compile, I'd like to learn why.

Comment: @mister_rampage Good question and I havent seen compile used all that much in the wild. Best resource as to why you would use it is over at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler Specifically see the `An Example of "Compile" Versus "Link"` section. Personally I've never really had a good use for compile myself.

Comment: @Beyers +1, I think the key statement in the doc is "This makes the scope model the single source of truth.". The whole manipulation of DOM to build the model seems to go against the point of Angular.